# Get matching pairs

Tags: php, mysql, match, union

Not an expert in MySQL nor PHP, but from the below MySQL database :

```
ID    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
id1   id2     id4     id3
id2   id3     id1     id6
id3   id8     id1     id5
id4   id3     id7     id5
id5   id9     id4     id1
```

How to be able to find matching pairs either in PHP or in MySQL so that the output would be (in this example):

```
id1-id2
id1-id3
id2-id1
id3-id1
id4-id5
id5-id4
```

The result shows the pairs that matched. For example, for row ID=id1, id2 is referenced in Col_A, and for ID=id2, id1 is referenced in Col_B, so they match : id1-id2 and id2-id1. But for row ID=id1, id4 is referenced in Col_B, if we look in row ID=id4, there is no reference to id1 in Col_A, Col_B nor Col_C, so there is no match.

I had a look at array_intersect_key in PHP but not sure how to handle the multiple recursivity here, and UNION in MySQL but have no idea where to start at neither.
The difference with what I saw on other questions is that here, the ID is used to match.

I need a bit of help here, thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't get your definition of matched pairs... Why `id1-id2` and `id1-id3` are pairs that matched but `id1-id4` are not?

Comment: It isn't at all clear how you are forming pairs.  Can you add some explanation?

Comment: yes sure, just added some explanation to explain more how to consider a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pain in MySQL, because it does not have CTEs.  The place to begin is unpivoting the data

```
select id, col_a as id2 from t union all
select id, col_b as id2 from t union all
select id, col_c as id2 from t;
```

Then, you simple want a self-join on this:

```
select t1.id, t1.id2
from (select id, col_a as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_b as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_c as id2 from t
     ) t1 join
     (select id, col_a as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_b as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_c as id2 from t
     ) t2
     on t1.id = t2.id2 and t1.id2 = t2.id
where t1.id < t1.id2;
```

Or, you could do this using `exists`:

```
select t.id, t.id2
from (select id, col_a as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_b as id2 from t union all
      select id, col_c as id2 from t
     ) t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id2 and t2.col_a = t.id) or
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id2 and t2.col_b = t.id) or
      exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id2 and t2.col_c = t.id);
```

Comment: works perfectly. doesnt display the 'duplicates' but it's fine, I understood the logic ! thanks